# Razor encodes everything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-encode

*Razor* is encoding every unicode character. How to prevent that?

**Example:**

This is my *Razor*:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.CategoriesList,
    "موضوع صفحه را انتخاب کنید...", new{
        @class = "form-control some-css"
    })
```

And this the rendered html:

```
<select class="form-control&#32;some-css" id="Category" name="Category">
    <option value="">
        &#1605;&#1608;&#1590;&#1608;&#1593; &#1589;&#1601;&#1581;&#1607; &#1585;&#1575; &#1575;&#1606;&#1578;&#1582;&#1575;&#1576; &#1705;&#1606;&#1740;&#1583;...
    </option>
    <option value="SomeValue">
        &#1605;&#1608;&#1586;&#1607;
    </option>
    <!-- some other options -->
</select>
```

Comment: Is your web.config set up to set utf-8 as your response encoding?

Comment: @DavidG Yes I think it is. I can't look at client-side source when I need it

Comment: @JasonTrue Not works. I tested: `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" uiCulture="fa-IR" />`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Html.Raw()`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CategoriesList,
    Html.Raw("موضوع صفحه را انتخاب کنید..."), new
    {
        @class = "form-control some-css"
    })
```

Comment: 1. `Html.DropDownListFor` accepts a `string` as label. 2. What about css-class provided. 3. What about other things? e.g. Other `option`s provided from list?

Comment: Your CSS classes are in Arabic?!

Comment: Nop. They are exactly what I write in Q. `form-control some-css`

Comment: So, what's the problem with the posted solution... I must be missing something